# JPA - Find items from a list that don't exist in a table

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

Given a list of emails, I need to find which ones don't exist in a table. Using SQL, I can do the following:

```
SELECT e.email 
FROM 
(
  VALUES('email1'),('email2'),('email3'),('email4')
) AS e(email)
EXCEPT
SELECT username FROM dbo.UsersTbl;
```

How can I write equivalent JPQL? In the application, values `email1`, `email2`... need be dynamically built (not hardcoded) based on passed in list. Using a Spring Data JPA native query, I can do the following:

```
@Query( value = 
"SELECT e.email " +
" FROM " +
"( " +
"  VALUES('email1'),('email2'),('email3'),('email4') " +
" ) AS e(email) " +
" EXCEPT " +
" SELECT username FROM dbo.UsersTbl ",
nativeQuery=true)
List<String> findMissingEmails(List<String> emails);
```

But how can I pass in the list of emails to the query?

Answer (score -1):

For fixed number of email arguments, this could work:

```java
@Query( value = 
"SELECT e.email " +
" FROM " +
"( " +
"  VALUES(:email1),(:email2),(:email3),(:email4) " +
" ) AS e(email) " +
" EXCEPT " +
" SELECT username FROM dbo.UsersTbl ",
nativeQuery=true)
List<String> findMissingEmails(String email1, String email2, String email3, String email4);
```

For high and/or dynamic number of emails, a better approach could be to use [NativeQuery](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-jpa-entitymanager-createnativequery-is-a-magic-wand/) constructed at runtime.

---

**Old answer** - more or less exactly the opposite of what was asked for, but I'll keep it here as reference.

Using of [named parameter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.named-parameters):

```java
    @Query("SELECT u.email FROM User AS u WHERE u.email NOT IN (:emails)")
    List<String> findMissingEmails(@Param("emails")Collection<String> emails);
```

Alternatively, you could use a [JPA query method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods):

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    List<User> findAllByEmailNotIn(Collection<String> emails);
}
```

Unfortunately that method would fetch and return a list of `User`s instead of list of their emails.

To fetch just emails you could use a [JPA projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections).

Assuming that `User` entity has a field of type `String` named `email`, the following projection could be used:

```java
public interface UserEmail {
    String getEmail();
}
```

And this is the repository method:

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    List<UserEmail> findAllByEmailNotIn(Collection<String> emails);
}
```